# Bulk API 2.0 trying to post new job, but request is redirected

Tags: bulk-api, node.js

I am trying to create bulk job using Bulk API 2.0, but my post request is redirected by salesforce to GET request. As a result, job is not created and I get /jobs/ingest GET response instead. I have no problem creating jobs when I use Workbench. And also my code easily gets job statuses and puts csv in /jobs/ID/batches.
I am using node.js and node-fetch.

Here is my code:

```
const params = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
  body: {
    operation: 'insert',
    object: 'Lead',
    contentType: 'CSV',
    lineEnding: 'CRLF',
  },
};
const response = await fetch(`https://mydomain--sandboxname.lightning.force.com/services/data/v43.0/jobs/ingest`, params);
const data = response.json();
```

This is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 02 Apr 2019 09:28:02 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536001; includeSubDomains
Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only: pin-sha256="9n0izTnSRF+W4W4JTq51avSXkWhQB8duS2bxVLfzXsY="; pin-sha256="5kJvNEMw0KjrCAu7eXY5HZdvyCS13BbA0VJG1RSP91w="; pin-sha256="njN4rRG+22dNXAi+yb8e3UMypgzPUPHlv4+foULwl1g="; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/hpkp-report/nullm";
Expect-CT: max-age=0; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/Expect-CT-report/nullm";
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests 
X-Robots-Tag: none
Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private
Set-Cookie: BrowserId=0xWavqFmQlW1Cmb5_1ccvw;Path=/;Domain=.force.com;Expires=Sat, 01-Jun-2019 09:28:02 GMT;Max-Age=5184000
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Location: https://mydomain--sandboxname.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/jobs/ingest
Content-Length: 0
```

I tried different urls (with .my.salesforce, with just salesforce.com), still no luck.

Comment: Your domain is mydomain--sandboxname.lightning.force.com but should be mydomain--sandboxname.my.salesforce.com . Please use instance name from auth token response

Comment: @pklochkov Would you like to post an answer so that this question can be closed?

Comment: @DavidReed done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain is mydomain--sandboxname.lightning.force.com but should be mydomain--sandboxname.my.salesforce.com .

Please use instance_url field from auth token response. Examples of how to perform this request you may find in [REST API guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_oauth_and_connected_apps.htm)